# Identity Server - IIS Settings - Anonymous and Windows Authentication?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identityserver3

I am setting up an IdentityServer that will work against windows AD for authentication. I currently have the webhost for IdentityServer setup in IIS to allow both anonymous access and windows access (mixed authentication) in order to work. The issue is I don't understand why I need windows authentication setup on this site? In fact, since I have anonymous enabled, I am not even sure how the windows auth is helping (but it seems to). I am guessing I am missing some concept, but I am seeing the following authentication flow:

1. User visits a client that requires authentication.
2. User is redirected to IdentityServer hosted site (OP).
3. The OP then looks up the providers, and sees that we have configured a ws-federation provider. User is then redirected to the ws-federation provider and authenticated.
4. User comes back to OP, and we have the token translation service configured. Token is translated and identity token is created and user is redirected back to client.

Based on this flow, the ws-federation provider is the one doing the windows authentication stuffs, and OP site should not need to be setup to require windows auth in IIS at this point. Am I missing something? Is the issue that I have the identity server and token translation service hosted in the same site ([following this example](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/WebHost%20(Windows%20Auth%20All-in-One)))?

Note: If I turn windows auth off on the OP IIS site, I get a blank page when visiting the /permissions page (and network traffic shows we get a 401 "not authorized" trying to access the windows token provider mapped url).

Comment: Is the WS-Fed provider and IdSrv hosted in the same application?

Comment: Yes. We are basically following this sample: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/WebHost%20(Windows%20Auth%20All-in-One

Comment: Am I wrong in using the combined setup as shown in the IdentityServer3 samples?

Comment: I am confused - you are using the sample that does cookies and windows authN in the same app - and you are wondering why you need to enable Windows authentication? because that's the way it works.